# How to fix code to make cover completely centered w/ CSS3

Tags: html, css, cover

Good Morning, I am currently working on portfolio and I am trying to make my cover elements completely center vertically and horizontal. I have managed to do this with `margin: 0 auto` and `display: table-cell`, `vertical-align` and for some reason when I am added my CSS3 triangles it began to push my logo to the left. Is there any tricks to fix this?

```css
.cover {
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: white;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20%;
  height: 1900px;
}
.logo-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#triangle-bottomright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #84cfc5;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  padding-top: 1500px;
  margin-left: 850px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#triangle-topright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid #84cfc5;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 1000px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: relative;
  left: -1000px;
  right: -1000px;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img class="logo" src="images/personal-logo.png" alt="logo-brand" />
  </div>
  <div id="triangle-topright"></div>
  <div id="triangle-bottomright"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with smaller units?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what does that mean?

Comment: Your units like padding-top: 1500px and so on.. have larger units. As I don't know the ratios between those units I can't make it run on fiddle properly. Could you make it small like 150px

Comment: @BreionnaDillon `background-position:center`?

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen I can't because they wont be directly positioned the way I want them. They are two triangles over my logo.

Comment: @Midas would that be the for the CSS cover attributed

Comment: [link]https://s31.postimg.org/8r02yay4b/Screen_Shot_2016_06_19_at_12_01_26_PM.png

Answer (score 0):

The triangles are causing a shift because they are taking up space in the page flow. You should position them using `position:absolute` to get them out of the page flow, with `position:relative` set on the parent `.cover` div. Example below.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.cover {
  background-color: white;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.logo-container {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#triangle-bottomright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #84cfc5;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#triangle-topright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid #84cfc5;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/240x80" alt="logo-brand" />
  </div>
  <div id="triangle-topright"></div>
  <div id="triangle-bottomright"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey thanks, but that didn't work for me. This is what I am trying to do but more vertically centered. https://s31.postimg.org/8r02yay4b/Screen_Shot_2016_06_19_at_12_01_26_PM.png

Comment: the example you have provided @midas

Comment: @BreionnaDillon Can you make a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your attempts?

Comment: Never heard of that jsFiddle? What is that? Sorry =(

Comment: It's an online editor to test HTML/CSS snippets... You go to [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), type in your code, click the update button and post the link back here.

Comment: i have also posted a screen shot as well

Comment: I have applied `position:relative` and `position:absolute` as I mentioned and it works fine: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/XL2000/cLgqwf3e/1/)

Comment: you had wanted to me removed my paddings and display and marign: 0 auto at first

Comment: it is working for the #triangle-bottomright CSS3 but not the top right one. GRRR LOL

Comment: @BreionnaDillon Is there a top right one? I only see top left and bottom right

Comment: no it was top-left i am reading my code backwards my apologies. its work beautifully thank you so much!